# Linux settings of bitrix site folder

Tags: php, html, linux, content-management-system, bitrix

I watched the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27t1QWuu06Q&list=PLY4rE9dstrJyqAWUVlT7PLGjdmPEwhfg6&index=3&t=262s. The path to the site on the main machine is `C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\mysite`, the path to the site on the virtual machine is `192.168.0.18\home\bitrix\www\mysite`. If I copy the downloaded `html` folder to `\home\bitrix\www`, then site displayed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pO6n.jpg)

if I copy to the folder `\home\bitrix\www\mysite`, then

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTEe1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qyFc.png)

Tell me how to make it appear when copying a folder one level down.

Answer (score 0):

After copying the `html` directory to `mysite` directory you should access it by `192.168.0.18/mysite/html` in the browser.

Actually `/home/bitrix/www` is your website's **Root Directory** so when you request for `192.168.0.18/html` after moving it to `mysite` directory, there is no `html` directory in Root Directory and you will get 404 error.